# Converting minutes to HH:MM when working with negative numbers in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to work out when employees have worked over or under the amount of hours they should be working by using a calculated field from the database which is in minutes. I have got some code that formats the minutes as HH:MM and it works fine with positive numbers but when it's a negative number, it does not work correctly.

```
RIGHT('0' + CAST (FLOOR(COALESCE (NO_MINS, 0) / 60) AS VARCHAR (8)), 2) + ':' + 
RIGHT('0' + CAST (FLOOR(COALESCE (NO_MINS, 0) % 60) AS VARCHAR (2)), 2) + ':' + 
RIGHT('0' + CAST (FLOOR((NO_MINS* 60) % 60) AS VARCHAR (2)), 2)
```

Example result:

When positive: 04:33:00

When negative: -2:0*:00

Is this possible?

Using SQL Server 2012.

Comment: How about taking the difference and getting the absolute value?  ( abs )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To modify your example as little as possible, and to point out the concept of "it works when positive and not negative" implies "use abs".

```
Declare @NO_MINS int

set @NO_MINS = 200

select
case when @NO_MINS < 0 then '-' else '' end +
RIGHT('0' + CAST (FLOOR(abs(COALESCE (@NO_MINS, 0)) / 60) AS VARCHAR (8)), 2) + ':' + 
RIGHT('0' + CAST (FLOOR(abs(COALESCE (@NO_MINS, 0)) % 60.0) AS VARCHAR (2)), 2) + ':' + 
RIGHT('0' + CAST (FLOOR(abs((@NO_MINS* 60) % 60.0)) AS VARCHAR (2)), 2) 

set @NO_MINS = -200

select
case when @NO_MINS < 0 then '-' else '' end +
RIGHT('0' + CAST (FLOOR(abs(COALESCE (@NO_MINS, 0)) / 60) AS VARCHAR (8)), 2) + ':' + 
RIGHT('0' + CAST (FLOOR(abs(COALESCE (@NO_MINS, 0)) % 60) AS VARCHAR (2)), 2) + ':' + 
RIGHT('0' + CAST (FLOOR(abs((@NO_MINS* 60) % 60)) AS VARCHAR (2)), 2)
```

Now, it's also worth mentioning that an integer number of minutes, if that's what your field contains, will never give you any number of seconds, so the second calculation can be removed and replaced with '00' .

```
case when NO_MINS < 0 then '-' else '' end +
RIGHT('0' + CAST (FLOOR(abs(COALESCE (NO_MINS, 0)) / 60) AS VARCHAR (8)), 2) + ':' + 
RIGHT('0' + CAST (FLOOR(abs(COALESCE (NO_MINS, 0)) % 60) AS VARCHAR (2)), 2) + ':00'
```

Comment: I think that's worked a treat! Can't test fully as I'm just about to leave for the day but I'll check on Monday and mark is as the answer then. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this. Simple and easy.

```
CASE WHEN NO_MINS < 0 THEN '-' ELSE '' END 
     + CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), DATEADD( MINUTE, ABS(ISNULL( NO_MINS, 0 ) ), '00:00:00'), 108 )
```